# Why my tablet is not compatible with my app on google play

Tags: android, android-manifest, tablet

I have the next Android.manifest to try to do my app to work on every tablet, although the design is not adapted to all. Whats wrong with my file, google play says my device is not compatible with the app.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="23"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25"
    tools:ignore="OldTargetApi"
    tools:overrideLibrary="eu.electronicid.sdk.videoid" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- GCM -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Comment: what version of android does your tablet use?

Comment: Android 7.0 :' (

Comment: Please share the link of your app and the name of your device

Comment: Is not public yet. But the android.manifest is well constructed, not?

Comment: You might not have the least available version of Google Play services in your tab. Try in different device which have same Android version.

Comment: Many tablets do not have fingerprint sensors. It is possible that `USE_FINGERPRINT` requires a fingerprint sensor. Try adding another `<uses-feature>` element, to say that `android.hardware.fingerprint` is not required. Also note that you have `GET_ACCOUNTS` listed twice and that there is no `READ_PROFILE` permission in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Android Permissions Overview page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview):

> If you don't provide the uses-feature tag, then when Google Play
>   sees that your app requests the corresponding permission, it assumes
>   your app requires this feature. So it filters your app from devices
>   without the feature, as if you declared android:required="true" in the
>    tag.

So, maybe your tablet does not have one of the required hardware (for example, fingerprint), and as it is not marked as not required inside a `uses-feature` tag, you can't install it.